# Setting mail from using ini_set not working

Tags: php, email, ini-set

I have a contact form with email script which worked fine when hosted on a windows server.  I recently changed to Linux and now it works, but is ignoring the ini_set command.

I have this:

```
ini_set("sendmail_from",'admin@mywebsite.com');
```

in my code and I receive an email, but it is from:

user_1065770274@linweb20.linvh1.myhosting company.co.uk

not the address specified.  Do I need to do something else if it is Linux?

Thank you

Claire

Comment: I have fixed this - it was a problem with my $header set up